# Is pointer pointing to a single item or to an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I'm coding up a cleanup utility that will store items to be cleaned up in a tuple and in case of an error condition will do appropriate action for each item in the tuple. Some of the typical items in the tuple would be pointers to objects that were allocated on the heap. When my cleanup handler decides to delete these objects, it must know whether it should use the vanilla delete expression or the array form of delete expression (delete[]). How would I go about determining whether an item in the tuple is a pointer to a single object or a pointer to an array of objects.

Here is a [sample implementation](https://ideone.com/nqp2HC). And here are the sections that are relevant to this question:

```
template<unsigned index, typename... Types>
struct TupleItemDeleter
{
    void operator() (std::tuple<Types...>& t)
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting item at index " << index << std::endl;
        delete std::get<index>(t); //HOWTO: delete[] or delete?
        TupleItemDeleter<index - 1, Types...>{}(t);
    }
};

template<typename... Types>
struct TupleItemDeleter<0, Types...> 
{
    void operator() (std::tuple<Types...>& t)
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting item at index 0" << std::endl;
        delete std::get<0>(t); //HOWTO: delete[] or delete?
    }
};

template<typename... Types>
void deleter(std::tuple<Types...>& t)
{
    constexpr auto tupleSize = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Types...>>::value;
    TupleItemDeleter<tupleSize - 1, Types...>{}(t);
}
```

PS: I tried std::is_array, it's not helpful in my case.

Comment: Here be dragons.  You need to re-think the whole design. Read up on "C++ RAII" and "C++  std::unique_ptr".

Comment: The problem is I'm working on a legacy codebase and I don't have the luxury of making wholesale changes. Incorporating something less invasive like this would be the best possible way forward for me.

Comment: A pointer is just an address. It doesn't know how the storage was allocated.

Comment: Gasp. Better thee than me.

Comment: It might take a day or a week or a month of inspecting the code to figure the best way out of this mess. I am afraid SO can't help you.

Comment: i do not think that there is a way to do so. As far as i conclude from your comment you might even have elements allocated by `malloc`. One needs to provide deleters for all those elements on the tuple as well (or at least a flag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't tell just from the pointer whether it points to a single object or an array - that's why there are two forms of `delete`, because the compiler can't tell either. You need to track the information in some other fashion.

Since you're already using a tuple, perhaps you could store an indicator there.

Comment: Nice comment. :-)

Comment: @JiveDadson I considered leaving it as a comment instead, but it really is the answer. I've been yelled at on other forums for leaving an answer as a comment.

Comment: That's a fair answer. I have a slightly different but related question: if the compiler is unaware that the pointer points to an array, how does the runtime know how much memory to cleanup when you use delete[]?

Comment: @DigitalEye If it were a struct rather than a tuple, that might be possible. But in that case there would be better ways.  But alas the fields of tuples do not have names. Users of tuples must know who's on first. It is unlikely he could add a field to a tuple without breaking code. We don't even know if he can change the definition of the tuple. There is no way to answer this question without carefully studying the code mess^H^H^H^H base.

Comment: @DigitalEye — array new stores information about the number of elements being allocated. That’s essential for types that have destructors, so that array delete can do the right thing. There’s no inherent problem that requires distinguishing allocation of single elements. That could be done via array new, too. The language design says that you don’t have to do that.

Comment: @Mark Ransom -  These are the internets. You just can't win.

Answer (score 1):

The question to ask yourself is how does the code currently know that a pointer is to an array, i.e. how does it know it can safely index a pointer, and also by how much?

If there is some model for that, even if it just a convention and is not well-coded, then you need to then find some way to pass that convention into your tuple.

One way would be to store a pair of pointer/member for those elements that need array deletion, even though you don't use the count, or create a smart pointer wrapper that also contains the count, and start using them in more of the code.

Another thought is that certain classes are perhaps always array allocated and others never are. You could write yourself a trait that tells you this per class behaviour, or you could add a destroy() to the classes that perform the correct operation on each class. You might also presume that any pointer to a simple type is likely to be array allocated, eg a character pointer is likely to be a string.

If you can be more aggressive in replacing the allocator for the classes, without actually editing the legacy code, you could decide that all operator new() for the classes that have the issue actually call operator new with a count of 1 ; or that all operator new() log the address to a hash table. If the address is found, then you need to use operator delete.